# Selenium click command target attribute doesn't work using xpath

Tags: click, target, selenium-ide

Trying to get #1 to work in Selenium IDE.  #2 works fine.  I'm trying to check the checkbox (input tag).  When I store the value of this xpath id, it finds the correct id.  But the click command can't interpret the result of the xpath expression as the id for some reason.

HTML: 
<input type="checkbox" id="ChkObject813844">

#1:

command: click
target: xpath=//input[contains(@id,'ChkObject')]/@id **<=== isn't working!**
value:

#2:

command: click
target: ChkObject813844 <=== is working!
value:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add a command prior to #1 to store the value of the id first.

command: storeValue
target: xpath=//input[contains(@id,'ChkObject')]/@id
value: var_id

command: click
target: ${var_id}
value: